# Grails: Adding to or modifying grails plugins

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

There's a plugin that I would like to add features since it is not quite usable (in a practical way). Do you create a new plugin or is it allowed to update the existing one?

Comment: Which plugin are you trying to modify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to add to an existing one.  Ideally the plugin's page on the plugin portal ( http://grails.org/plugins/) should have a link to the source which is usually in subversion or git.  If it's in Subversion or a private GIT repo you might have to email the grails developer list ( http://grails.org/Mailing+lists) and ask for permission to the repo.  If it's in a public GIT repo you should be able to fork it, make your changes, and submit a pull request.

For example the Grails Cloud Foundry plugin ( http://grails.org/plugin/cloud-foundry) source code is located at ( https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-cloud-foundry)

If for some reason whoever owns the repo or plugin isn't working on it anymore it may make sense to create your own.  ( http://grails.org/Creating+Plugins)

Comment: As a matter of courtesy, try and get in touch with the plugin author before releasing a new version. You should be able to find their email address in either the source file headers or the plugin descriptor