# How can I have persistence Modifying a Grails plugin?

Tags: grails, plugins, repository, export, grails-plugin

I'm developing a grails application that uses  `export:1.6` plugin, but for particular reasons in some cases the result of an action using services is wrong, so I had to get in the methods of the plugin and I had to make son modifications inside the plugin, trouble comes when I want to commit it in our SVN repository (because we are working in a develop team), I'm going to update the app with the plugin modified, but when another person downloads it, the original plugin is going to be originally installed. So I thought to create a new plug in, but, do you have any another suggestion? or if the best way is to create a new plugin, how can I publish it in our Repo? oris it possible to download it with my changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8825485/grails-adding-to-or-modifying-grails-plugins). In your case, you are better off creating a new plugin.